# How can I find all matching input elements within given ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('#foo input');
$('#foo').find('input');
```

Both I believe get only the inputs straight descendant to #foo (ie. only the inputs nested immediately within foo). How can I get all the inputs, no matter how deeply nested in #foo?

Edit: Bah, this works. Sloppy me. Need coffee. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `#foo input` should find all input descendants of `#foo`.

Read the [documentation on CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) for more information and options.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these get all descendant inputs.

If you wanted only immediate children, you would do:

```
$('#foo > input');
$('#foo').children('input');
```

Selectors:

- http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/  *(all descendants)*
- http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/       *(immediate descendants)*

Methods:

- http://api.jquery.com/find/  *(all descendants)*
- http://api.jquery.com/children/  *(immediate descendants)*

Answer (score 0):

Your code does exactly what you want. It will match any INPUT element which is a child, grandchild, etc of #foo.

The way to get an element which is a direct child of foo would be

```
$("#foo>input");
```

Answer (score 0):

No you are not right, at least

```
$('#foo input');
```

does the job - according to http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/ gives all the input descendats of #foo. It is very similar to css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo > input');
```